# ¿como puedo pasar una variable a un innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, variables, innerhtml

tengo este Objeto creado:

```
class classeStats{
   constructor(clase, morale, power){
        this.clase = clase;
        this.morale = morale;
        this.power = power;
   }
}
const beor = new classeStats('beor', 210, 100);

var basicStats = ["morale", "power"];

for(const stat  of  basicStats){
        document.getElementById(`clase_td_${stat}`).innerHTML = beor.stat;
}
```

y tengo una tabla que quiero que me llene en las diferentes celdas con su importe del "stat",
pero no se si se puede hacer de esta manera... he intentado pasar también :

```
        document.getElementById(`clase_td_${stat}`).innerHTML = `beor.${stat}`;
```

no me coge el valor sino que lo hace como "string".

Comment: Intenta `document.getElementById(`clase_td_${stat}`).innerHTML = beor[stat];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente te recomiendo que si vas a hacer cambios en el DOM, lo hagas con Jquery porque te resultaría mas fácil.

lo segundo creo que te refieres a esto:

```
class classeStats{
   constructor(clase, morale, power){
        this.clase = clase;
        this.morale = morale;
        this.power = power;
   }
}

beor = new classeStats('beor', 210, 100); // no se muy bien porque lo haces constante
var basicStats = ["morale", "power"];

for(stat  of  basicStats){
  document.getElementById('clase_td_' + stat).innerHTML = beor[stat];
}
```

Comment: gracias!! era lo que buscaba :)

Comment: No es cierto que los cambios en el DOM sean más fáciles cuando se usa jQuery,  ten en cuenta que jQuery no es más que una librería, es mucho mejor trabajar con Javascript puro. También, @MarcTarrés, conviene saber que la notación de corchete debe ser usada siempre que vayas a usar datos dinámicos para acceder a las propiedades de los objetos ([está explicado claramente aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)). Eso es debido a la especificación misma de Javascript, para evitar errores.